# Send 100+ request continuously using NSURLConnection and wait for every response before sending next request

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsurl, nsurlrequest

how to send  100+ request continuously using NSURLConnection and wait for every response before sending next request, while sending the request for 100 loops,response is received only for first four or five requests, the remaining requests get response as request timeout, please help me with some sample code or reference

```
NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
_Connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
```

Comment: Why not send it al in one request instead of 100+ seperate?

Comment: You want response be return synchronously before sending next request? is this what you want?

Comment: Send the next request in the delegate method in which you get the response.

Comment: yes you are absolutely correct user2829759

Comment: i use for loop for sending the request continuously

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Call `startGenerator` method with `0` value as parameter from where you want start.

```
+(void)startGenerator:(int)counter { 

     NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
    [NSURLConnection request
                                           queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                               completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
           if (error == nil) {
              //Your Response parse and other stuff
              dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 5 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    // Make next request after  5 second after completion of current request.  
                    counter++;
                    if (counter<limitOfURL)
                         [self startGenerator];
              });
           }
   }];
```

Hope this help you.